# What is the mime type for .log files?

Tags: mime-types

I am building a mime-type guesser and I am using the `mimetype` command to check my results. For log files it is returning `text/x-log`. I dont see this mime type on these lists:

- http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types?view=markup
- https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Answer (score 19):

According to this link, it is 'text/plain', hope that helps.

https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/

Comment: is there a way to get application/octet-stream

Comment: But what lends credence to their assertion? To label it as merely `text/plain` seems regressive. Though, https://github.com/buildkite/agent/issues/983#issue-431035282 does provide some additional evidence.